# Translating an OpenGL ES 2.0 shader code to Metal (for ARKit scene)

Tags: swift, opengl-es, arkit, metal, fragment-shader

In the past, we had code written in the OpenGL ES 2.0 shader language we used in the Scenekit class. But OpenGL is no longer available for ARkit it's deprecated. Therefore, we have to rewrite these shader codes for Metal, which were written for OpenGL ES 2.0.

But the Metal library is quite new to me and I have trouble understanding it.

Below is one of our simple shader codes written in OpenGL ES 2.0 language. If you help me translate this, it basically helps me understand its logic so I can translate the others.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```cpp
precision highp float;

varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
varying vec2 textureCoordinate2;

uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;

void main() {

    vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
    vec4 base = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate2);

    vec2 colorCoords = vec2((1.0 + textureCoordinate.x) * 0.5,textureCoordinate.y);
    vec2 alphaCoords = vec2(textureCoordinate.x * 0.5,textureCoordinate.y);
    vec4 color = texture2D(inputImageTexture, colorCoords);
    float alpha = texture2D(inputImageTexture, alphaCoords).r;

    vec4 overlay = vec4(color.rgb, alpha);

    vec4 c2 = base;
    vec4 c1 = overlay;

    vec4 outputColor;

    //   outputColor.r = c1.r + c2.r * c2.a * (1.0 - c1.a);
    //   outputColor.g = c1.g + c2.g * c2.a * (1.0 - c1.a);
    //   outputColor.b = c1.b + c2.b * c2.a * (1.0 - c1.a);
    //   outputColor.a = c1.a + c2.a * (1.0 - c1.a);

    float a = c1.a + c2.a * (1.0 - c1.a);
    float alphaDivisor = a + step(a, 0.0); // Protect against a divide-by-zero blacking out things in the output

    outputColor.r = (c1.r * c1.a + c2.r * c2.a * (1.0 - c1.a))/alphaDivisor;
    outputColor.g = (c1.g * c1.a + c2.g * c2.a * (1.0 - c1.a))/alphaDivisor;
    outputColor.b = (c1.b * c1.a + c2.b * c2.a * (1.0 - c1.a))/alphaDivisor;
    outputColor.a = a;

    gl_FragColor = outputColor;
}
```

Comment: If you [download MoltenGL](https://moltengl.com/downloads/), you can use the included shader converter tool to convert OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders to Metal Shading Language. You don't need to purchase a MoltenGL license to run the converter tool.

You can also do the same using [MoltenVK](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/MoltenVK), which is open source. It is targeted for Vulkan, so focusses on converting SPIR-V shader code, but the shader converter tool with MoltenVK will convert all the way from GLSL to MSL too. 

Disclosure...I am the lead dev for both MoltenGL and MoltenVK.

Comment: @BillHollings Thank you for your suggestions and alternatives I will try one. Also, this work you do is tremendous!

Comment: @BillHollings Saw now. Downloaded MoltenGL today to try that. Are the OpenGLES uniform properties in Swift scenekit files that connect to the shader totally compatible or is it necessary to redo those also? Also, any  recommendations on optimizing fractal iterations performance? Thanks in advance!